# close a port in cmd

Tags: android, tcp, cmd, port

I need to use port `5037` under windows for `adb` (android).

When I type:

```
G:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools>adb nodaemon server
```

It gives:

```
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
```

This means that port `5037` is currently occupied...

When I type:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>netstat -ano | findstr "5037"
```

It gives:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16836
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52818        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52819        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52820        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52821        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52823        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:52824        TIME_WAIT       0
....(a lot of such)
TCP    127.0.0.1:53097        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53110        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53111        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    127.0.0.1:53118        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
....(a lot of such)
```

What should I do to clear port `5037`?

Comment: Identify process 16836 and work out whether it should be running and whether it should be using that port. If you can reconfigure it, do that, or else use a different port yourself. You can't run around killing random processes just to make your own software run.

Comment: I can not kill 16838, because of `access rejected`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type "tasklist" in cmd console to find which process occupy port 5037, then go to task manager to kill such process.

Comment: Neat and effective. Absolutely best answer. Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

The command is

> taskkill /F /PID "PID_Number"

"PID_Number" should be from the task that is marked as LISTENING.
In your case,

> netstat -ano | findstr 5037
>
> taskkill /F /PID **16836**

Answer (score 0):

If you used genymotion, you would go to settings in genymotion. In adb tab, check use custom android sdk tools and browse to add your adb dir. Then, it worked ok.
I think that conflict between genytion adb and your adb.